# Edit a template inside the embedded console. Like: /templates/{templateId}/views/edit

Tags: templates, docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign API to create Templates. To edit the template, we get the embedded console url, and navigate to Templates, find the template we want to edit, and the select edit. Is there a way to get a url to directly edit the template inside the embedded console? Something like: /templates/{0}/views/edit

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can, do a [Post Sender view](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Sender%20View.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____93) but replace the envelope ID with the template ID and it will give you the URL to a session where you can modify the template.

Comment: One thing to note: It works if you're using the classic docusign experience. The template doesn't seem to load correctly in the new look.

Comment: Good catch, I will confirm whether it is on our roadmap to include in the NDSE.

Comment: @tsides Just confirmed it is something on the road map for the New DocuSign Experience but unfortunately we have no timeframe yet.